# How to send email attachments with microsoft exchange?

Tags: java, email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I want to send email attachements through Exchange server using java. Sending email is working fine:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(username,password);
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUrl(new URI(MailHost));

EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
msg.setSubject("My Subject!");
msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("My Message"));
msg.getToRecipients().add(mailTo);
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What API are the exchange classes from? Why can't you just use smtp?

Comment: And which `EmailMessage` implementation? There seem to be quite a few unrelated ones out there.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Exchange api is the same as used here: http://www.aaronheld.com/post/reading-exchange-mail-with-java    EmailMessage class microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution [HERE](http://techjava-mistakes.blogspot.com/2013/03/ews-java-send-mail-with-attachment.html)

```
public boolean sendEWSMail(String subject, String bodyContent, String to, String cc){
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    EmailMessage msg = null; 
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = null;
    String domain = "domain name";
    if (domain == null || domain.equals("")) {
        credentials = new WebCredentials("username", 
                "password");
    } else {
        credentials = new WebCredentials("username", 
                "password", domain);
    }
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    try {
        service.setUrl(new URI("Mail server URL"));
        msg = new EmailMessage(service);
        msg.setSubject(subject); 
        msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText(bodyContent));
        msg.getAttachments().addFileAttachment("Complete File Path");
        if(to == null || to.equals("")){
            LOGGER.warn("To distribution list is empty. Could not send the mail ");
        }else{
            String[] mailTos = to.split(";");
            for(String mailTo : mailTos){
                if(mailTo != null && !mailTo.isEmpty())
                msg.getToRecipients().add(mailTo);
            }
            if(cc != null && !cc.isEmpty()){
                String[] mailCCs = cc.split(";");
                for(String mailCc : mailCCs){
                    if(mailCc != null && !mailCc.equals(""))
                    msg.getCcRecipients().add(mailCc);
                }
            }
            msg.send();
            LOGGER.debug("Mail successfully send ");
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while sending EWS Mail ", e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so you have answered your own question and the bounty is gone. Anyway, as a side note and because I wanted to try and help you: Do you know of any Exchange Server test environments available via internet for developers who do not have access to a "real" Exchange corporate server?

Comment: Yes I know but as I saw such a low number of views I just posted the answer after I found it. About your question I don't know any one.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (2016) you could also use the [new Outlook Email API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Createattachments) and send RESTful requests from the java code using an [OutlookClient](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjp_OPrsLLLAhXJd5oKHWHhCPcQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FOfficeDev%2FOffice-365-SDK-for-Java%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fsdk%2Foutlook-services%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fmicrosoft%2Fservices%2Foutlook%2Ffetchers%2FOutlookClient.java&usg=AFQjCNFTWREZ3qtbaYYHINkSOCleu4wbvQ).

See [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Java/blob/master/sdk/outlook-services/src/main/java/com/microsoft/services/outlook/Message.java) too.